# PHP return number format

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am using PHP to count rows from the SQL DB. Now i want to format the counts with a thousandsseperator.

The current code looks like this:

```
public function countFollowers(){
        if (empty($this->user_id) || !is_numeric($this->user_id)) {
            return false;
        }

        $user_id = $this->user_id;
        $t_conn  = T_CONNECTIV;
        self::$db->where('following_id',$user_id)->where('type',1);
        return self::$db->getValue($t_conn,"COUNT(`id`)");
    }
```

And on the html side with this:

```
<?php echo $context['user_followers']; ?>
```

The current output looks like this 2340 !
How can i format this output like this 2.340 ? With a point as thousandseperator?

Comment: [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) has what you need

Comment: Try: `<?php echo number_format( $context['user_followers'], 0, ',', '.' ); ?>`